# Две функции с таймером в рекурсии дают "странный" результат с изменением размера изображения

Tags: рекурсия, таймер

Мне нужно было получить код, который динамически бы менял размер рисунка по нажатию определенной кнопки. В итоге должно было получиться две кнопки "увеличение" и "уменьшение" размера. На каждую кнопку соответственно "вешалась" функция изменения размера рисунка. 
Полученный код давал эффект, что при запуске одной функции - размер "рисунка" меняется, но если запустить следом другую - результат "странный", размер не меняется последовательно, а колеблется в рамках указанного изменения в 1 px.

Ниже показан код, который был в последствии изменен и это изменение содержит комментарий.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
 <title>Картинки</title> 
</head>

<body>
 
 <a href="javascript:resizeImg1()">Растягивание картинки</a>
 <a href="javascript:resizeImg2()">Стягивание картинки</a>

  <img src="" width="200" height="200">
 

 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  function resizeImg1(){
   var img = document.images[0];
   if (img.width < 400){
    img.width += 1;
    img.height += 1;
   }
   else {return;} /*этой строки не было первоначально и это 
создавало проблему "дрожания". добавление этой строки решает проблему "дрожания" размеров изображения*/
   setTimeout("resizeImg1()", 2);
  }
  
  function resizeImg2(){
   var img = document.images[0];
   if (img.width > 100){
    img.width -= 1;
    img.height -= 1;
   }
   else {return;} /*этой строки не было первоначально и это 
создавало проблему "дрожания". добавление этой строки решает проблему "дрожания" размеров изображения*/
   setTimeout("resizeImg2()", 2);
  }
 </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Все правильно, первая функция увеличивает, вторая - уменьшает.

Comment: Кстати, кто вас учил передавать в `setTimeout` строку? Больше ничему там не учитесь лучше.

Comment: убрал строку, поставил просто имя функции. результат такой же. когда первая функция отработала, и картинка стала больше - вторая функция, которая ее уменьшает, срабатывает странно. первый ее запуск заставляет картинку "дрожать". второй ее вызов уменьшает, но далее уменьшенная картинка тоже "дрожит". т.е. функция не прекращает работу продолжает как-то менять размер. вот что в этот момент происходит и почему не прекращается работа функции - для меня загадка.

Comment: Я уже писал вам, почему происходит "дрожание"

Comment: Все правильно, первая функция увеличивает, вторая - уменьшает. 
Кстати, кто вас учил передавать в setTimeout строку? Больше ничему там не учитесь лучше. – это все что я нашел)

Comment: прошу прощения, но я не понял где находится ответ)

Comment: Повторяю: картинка дрожит потому что первая функция ее постоянно увеличивает, а вторая - уменьшает.

Comment: да. понял. единственно пока не догадался, как завершить работу функции, чтобы они не работали одновременно. самовызов анонимной функции внутри функции и далее return не дали результат

Comment: Для начала, завершите работу функции когда она закончит анимацию. Точнее, не продолжайте работу функции.

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, идею варианта - как в таком случае завершить работу первой функции до вызова второй

Comment: спасибо! разобрался else {return;} кстати строку в setTimeout научил Игорь Борисов из "Специалиста".

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на [switch](http://javascript.ru/switch). Заверните функции в switch/case и поставьте условие: так вы сможете контролировать вызов функции.

Comment: нормально отрабатывает теперь с else {return;} перед таймером.  спасибо.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Добрый день, Николас. Постараюсь последовать вашему совету. В этот раз, очевидно, неточно сформулировал - чего ждал от кода:).